# Depends on query change document in mongoose pre('update')

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, middleware

I want to change `lastActiveAt` field everytime when model is updated with `{active: true}`. I have something like this:

```
MySchema.pre('update', function(next) {
  if (this._compiledUpdate.$set.active) {
    this.update({}, {lastActiveAt: new Date()});
  }
  next();
});

// ...

MyModel.update({/* ... */}, {active: true});
```

It works but I don't like that underscore in `_compiledUpdate`. Is there a recommended way to access query in pre('update') middleware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `this.getUpdate()` method to get the update query:

```
MySchema.pre('update', function(next) {
  if (this.getUpdate().$set.active) {
    this.update({}, {lastActiveAt: new Date()});
  }
  next();
});
```

Ref: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2812